# Is there a 'make' rule to run a command exactly once but only if the rest of the makefile has something to do?

Tags: makefile, rules

Imagine that I want to put a special stamp (don't worry about the contents of that stamp) on any executable I build.  I have a rule to create the stamp itself.  But I do NOT want the stamp being recreated UNLESS the rest of the makefile would do something:

And it has to work with make -j (parallel).  Here is a pseudo-code makefile to start with (it does not work):

```
all: a b

.PHONY: buildstamp
buildstamp: all
        date > buildstamp.txt

a: a.cpp
        cp buildstamp.txt a

b: b.cpp
        cp buildstamp.txt b
```

Again, buildstamp should only run when ANY target would be updated, and even then it should only exactly run once (not once per target).  And it must complete before any of those targets run obviously (otherwise buildstamp.txt might have a partial result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.PHONY: all

all: a b

a b: %: %.cpp buildstamp.txt 
        cp buildstamp.txt $@

buildstamp.txt: a.cpp b.cpp
        date > buildstamp.txt
```